# Statically link custom op from .a file in tensorflow serving

Tags: tensorflow-serving

I have a custom op implemented CUDA and built using Makefile like this [hdrnet](https://github.com/mgharbi/hdrnet/blob/master/hdrnet/Makefile). I can build .so and import in tensorflow. For tf-serving statically linking .a file is required but all tutorials reference bazel build process for [custom op](https://github.com/tensorflow/custom-op) instead of directly linking compiled op from .a file. 
Do I have to write build process as referenced by examples or I can build tf-serving with .so/.a files directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up compile tensorflow-serving from source with op-linked in. Tensorflow tutorials are not complete for this and additional dependency was missing which I resolved in this issue [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60374967/tensorflow-serving-custom-gpu-op-cannot-find-dependency-when-compiling).